# Angular loading specific 3rd party scripts in partial views ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my app I have ui-router set up, and in one particular state i.e. "MAP" I want to load a 3rd party Javascript file.

Right now I have it as part of my Index.html at the bottom of the page. But i thought it would be better practice to only load this in view which needs it.

What is the best way to include this script in only specific partial views ?

Comment: Incredible - I was just about to ask the same question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can simply include the `<script>` tag in your partial. Works perfectly fine for me.

Also, if you have a `window.onload` function, you can replace it with a self invoking function like

```
(function(param){
     alert("partial running");
     bla bla....
})();
```

so it will run when the partial is pulled up.